# Angular 8 Can't change fill color of inline SVG

Tags: css, svg, angular8, inline-svg

I'm having some problems filling an InlineSVG. I have a `div` with the svg:

```
<div class="svg-div" [inlineSVG]="'../../../assets/images/add.svg'"></div>
```

Then in CSS:

```
.svg-div {
    fill: blue;
}
```

but the icon remains grey.

I've also tried:

```
.svg-div ::ng-deep svg{
    fill: blue;
}
```

in different combinations, but nothing worked.
[Here is the link to my stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/svg-inline-7xmufx). What's wrong?

Comment: remove the fill attribute from the SVG file.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because fill attribute is hardcoded in your svg file. Remove **fill="#7A7A7A"** from your svg file then you will be able to change color through css.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add path to css

```
::ng-deep svg path {
  fill: blue;
}
```

[image]